# How can we show that this is a stopping time?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times, quadratic-variation, local-martingales

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a complete probability space
- $T>0$
- $I:=(0,T]$
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in\overline I}$ be a complete and right-continuous filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$
- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$
- $M:\Omega\times\overline I\times\Lambda\to\mathbb R$ such that $M(x)$ is a continuous local $\mathcal F$-martingale on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ for all $x\in\Lambda$ and $$A(x,y):=[M(x),M(y)]\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in\Lambda,$$ where $[M(x),M(y)]$ denotes the quadratic covariation of $M(x)$ and $M(y)$

Now, let $\beta\in(0,1]$, $$\left\|f\right\|_{C^{0+\beta}(K)}:=\sup_{\stackrel{x,\:y,\:x',\:y'\:\in\:K}{x\:\ne\:x',\:y\:\ne\:y'}}\frac{\left|f(x,y)-f(x',y)-f(x,y')+f(x',y')\right|}{\left|x-x'\right|^\beta\left|y-y'\right|^\beta}$$ for $K\subseteq\Lambda$ and $f:\Lambda\times\Lambda\to\mathbb R$. Let $K\subseteq\Lambda$ be compact and assume $$\left\|A_t\right\|_{C^{0+\beta}(K)}<\infty\;\;\;\text{almost surely for all }t\in\overline I\tag1,$$ where $A_t=A(\;\cdot\;,t,\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;)$. Moreover, assume that $\overline I\ni t\mapsto A(\omega,t\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;)$ is continuous with respect to $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{C^{0+\beta}(K)}$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$.

> Let $C>0$. How can we show that $$\tau:=\inf\left\{t\in\overline I:\left\|A_t\right\|_{0+\beta}\ge C\right\}$$ is a $\mathcal F$-stopping time?

Let $t\in\overline I$. The imposed continuity assumptions implies that $$\left\{\tau\le t\right\}=\left\{\sup_{s\:\in\:[0,\:t]}\left\|A_s\right\|_{C^{0+\beta}(K)}\ge C\right\}.\tag1$$

> My problem is that I don't see why the set on the right-hand side belongs to $\mathcal F_t$. By the continuity assumption, this reduces to the question why $\left\|A_s\right\|_{C^{0+\beta}(K)}$ is $\mathcal F_s$-measurable for all $s\in\overline I$.

Maybe we're able to prove that by showing that the supremum in the definition of $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{C^{0+\beta}(K)}$ is equal to the supremum over a dense subset of $K$ (which exists, since $K$ is separable).

Comment: What's $A_t$?..

Comment: @mathworker21 $A_t=A(\;\cdot\;,t,\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;)$ as usual.

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: @zhoraster The question is based on theorem 3.1.1 of book "Stochastic flows and stochastic differential equations" by Kunita. I've got a hard time to understand his definitions and his ideas behind the proofs. See my other questions ([(1)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303857/regularity-of-martingales-with-respect-to-spatial-parameters) and [(2)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301636/prove-that-a-local-martingale-with-spatial-parameter-is-differentiable)), if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, 
$$
\big|[M(x),M(y)]_t - [M(x'),M(y)]_t - [M(x),M(y')]_t + [M(x'),M(y')]_t\big|\\ = \big|[M(x)-M(x'),M(y)-M(y')]_t\big|\le \left([M(x)-M(x')]_t[M(y)-M(y')]_t\right)^{1/2},
$$
so the supremum in the definition of $A$ is attained for $\{x,x'\}=\{y,y'\}$. Even more important, by the triangle inequality 
$$
|[M(x)]^{1/2}_t - [M(x')]^{1/2}_t|\le [M(x)-M(x')]_t^{1/2},
$$
so $[M(\cdot)]^{1/2}_t$, hence$[M(\cdot)]_t$, is almost surely continuous (even Hölder continuous). Then $A$ is (jointly) continuous as well:
$$
|A_t(x,y)-A_t(x',y')|\le\big|[M(x),M(y)]_t - [M(x'),M(y)]_t\big|\\ + \big|[M(x'),M(y)]_t - [M(x'),M(y')]_t\big|\\ \le  \sup_{K}[M(\cdot)]_t^{1/2} \big([M(x)-M(x')]_t^{1/2} + [M(y)-M(y')]_t^{1/2}\big)\\
\le  \sup_{K}[M(\cdot)]_t^{1/2} ||A_t||_{C^{0+\beta}(K)}^{1/2}\big(|x-x'|^{\beta} + |y-y'|^{\beta}\big).
$$
So indeed, the supremum is attained over some fixed countable set, which implies the desired meausurability of $A_t$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I agree that $$\big|[M(x),M(y)]-[M(x'),M(y)]-[M(x),M(y')]+[M(x'),M(y')]\big|\le\left([M(x)-M(x')][M(y)-M(y')]\right)^{1/2}$$ almost surely for all $x,y,x',y'\in\Lambda$ (i.e., the null set doesn't depend on time, but on $x,y,x',y'$). Now, we can choose a countable dense subset $Q$ of $K$ and it's clear to me that $$\left\|A_t\right\|_{C^{0+\beta}(Q)}=\sup_{\stackrel{x,\:x'\:\in\:Q}{x\:\ne\:x'}}\frac{[M(x)-M(x')]_t}{\left|x-x'\right|^{2\beta}}$$ almost surely for all $t\in\overline I$. But how exactly do you conclude the measurability of the right-hand side?

Comment: Supremum of a countable family of random variables is measurable.

Comment: Yes, I know that. What I've meant (and I see that I didn't phrase my question well) is how do you conclude the measurability of the right-hand side, if $Q$ is replaced by $K$. I guess this is similar to the fact that for a continuous function $g$ from a topological space $X$ to a normed space $Y$, $\sup_A\left\|f\right\|_Y=\sup_{\overline A}\left\|f\right\|_Y$ for all $A\subseteq X$.

Comment: But here things are different, at least since $A$ is not jointly (only separately) continuous.

Comment: @0xbadf00d, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Your answer is really helpful to me. Just one last thing: You wrote that $[M(\;\cdot\;)]_t$ is almost surely continuous; are you sure? Note that we've got $[M(x)-M(x')]_t$ in the supremum, not $|[M(x)]-[M(x')]|$.

Comment: By the latter is controlled by the former (e.g. by the triangle inequality), see the updated answer.

Comment: What kind of triangle inequality is this? I'm sorry, but I don't understand how you obtain $|[M(x)]^{1/2}_t - [M(x')]^{1/2}_t|\le [M(x)-M(x')]_t^{1/2}$.

Comment: The last thing you said. Ok, take some partitions, write the usual inequality for Euclidean norms $$\left(\sum_{i} (\Delta X_{t_i}+ \Delta Y_{t_i})^2\right)^{1/2} \le   \left(\sum_{i} (\Delta X_{t_i})^2\right)^{1/2} + \left(\sum_{i} (\Delta Y_{t_i})^2\right)^{1/2}$$ and proceed to the limit as diameter of parittion goes to zero to get $[X + Y]^{1/2} \le [X]^{1/2} + [Y]^{1/2}$.

(It's also possible to control one term in terms of the other by the Cauchy--Schwartz.)

Comment: Finally got it. Thank you very much, once again. The question was motivated by a lack of rigor in the proof of Theorem 3.1.1 of the book "Stochastic flows and stochastic differential equations" by Kunita. Therein $A$ is not defined to be $(x,y)\mapsto[M(x), M(y)]$, but to merely be a modification with the property $(1)$ of it. Do you think that your proof still goes through under this assumption? The problematic thing is the selection of common null sets.

Comment: I don't know, frankly. Kunita is certainly hard to read.

Comment: If I'm not terribly wrong, you've made one mistake in your reasoning: The crucial inequalities $$\big|[M(x),M(y)] - [M(x'),M(y)] - [M(x),M(y')] + [M(x'),M(y')]\big|\le \left([M(x)-M(x')][M(y)-M(y')]\right)^{1/2}\tag2$$ and $$|[M(x)]^{1/2} - [M(x')]^{1/2}|\le [M(x)-M(x')]^{1/2}\tag3$$ only hold almost surely with null sets depending on the spatial parameters.

Comment: So, the only thing we can conclude is $$\sup_{\stackrel{x,\:x'\:\in\:Q}{x\:\ne\:x'}}\frac{\left|[M(x)]^{1/2}_t-[M(x')]^{1/2}_t\right|}{{d(x,x')}^\beta}\le\sup_{\stackrel{x,\:x'\:\in\:Q}{x\:\ne\:x'}}\frac{[M(x)-M(x')]^{1/2}_t}{{d(x,x')}^\beta}=\left\|A_t\right\|_{C^{0+\beta}(Q)}^{1/2}$$ almost surely for all $t$, where $Q$ is a fixed countable subset of $K$. The problem is that this doesn't yield the continuity of $[M(\;\cdot\;)]_t$.

Comment: The two inequalities hold for all $\omega$, not almost surely.

Comment: Why should they? $[M,N]$ is only defined up to indistinguishability. So, the strongest relations involving $[M,N]$ that you can prove are those which hold almost surely.

Comment: I see what you mean. Was thinking about strict pathwise sense. Ok, I'll think tomorrow.

Comment: I didn't have a chance to think, probably there is indeed a gap after all. But I had a chance to look into Kunita. I think that $\bar C^{0,\delta}$ ($C^{0+\beta}$ in your notation) consists of continuous functions by his definition. He writes, "For $g\in \bar C^m$ define a seminorm...", and $\bar C^m$ consists of functions, which are $m$ times continuously differentiable (read: have $m$ (jointly) continuous derivatives). In our case, $m=0$, so $g$ is just (jointly) continuous. That's how I understand this.

Comment: Okay, assuming joint continuity, would this solve the problem mentioned above?

Comment: Yes. The supremum will then be attained at a countable set.

Comment: I think that there is still a gap: Assuming joint continuity of the elements of $C^{0+\beta}(K)$, we clearly have $$\left\|A_t\right\|_{C^{0+\beta}(K)}=\left\|A_t\right\|_{C^{0+\beta}(Q)}.$$ The goal is to show continuity of $[M(\;\cdot\;)]_t$, but we still only have $$\sup_{\stackrel{x,\:x'\:\in\:Q}{x\:\ne\:x'}}\frac{\left|[M(x)]^{1/2}_t-[M(x')]^{1/2}_t\right|}{{d(x,x')}^\beta}\le\sup_{\stackrel{x,\:x'\:\in\:Q}{x\:\ne\:x'}}\frac{[M(x)-M(x')]^{1/2}_t}{{d(x,x')}^\beta}=\left\|A_t\right\|_{C^{0+\beta}(Q)}^{1/2}.\tag4$$ (We would need that the supremum on the left-hand side can be taken over $K$)

Comment: Forget everything about Cauchy-Schwartz. You're interested in supremum of something continuous.  It is attained on a countable set.

Comment: Oops, forgot about the actual problem. What do you think he's meaning by a "continuous" $\tilde C^{0,\:β}$-process (I'm using his notation now in order to prevent confusion)? It should mean that $t\mapsto A_t(\omega)$ is continuous from $\overline I$ to $\tilde C^{0,\:β}$ for all $\omega$. If that's the case, in his theorem he's claiming that $M_t\in C^{0,\:\alpha}$ almost surely for all $t$ (i.e. $M$ has a modification of a $C^{0,\:α}$-process) for all $α\in(0,\beta)$. That's actually clear to me now. But how do we see that this modification is continuous (from $\overline I$ to $C^{0,\:α}$)?

Comment: Again, it seems that for Kunita $\tilde C^{0,\alpha}$ by definition consists of continuous functions. (Continuity in $t$ is not relevant here.)

Comment: You've misunderstood me. In the theorem, he's talking about "*continuous* $\tilde C^{0,\:\beta}$-processes" and that notion of continuity here has to be understood as a path property (as usual). That continuity of $A$ (he's actually using the same symbol in his proof) is already needed to conclude $\left\|A_t^{\tau_n}\right\|_{\tilde C^{0,\:\beta}(K)}\le n$.

Comment: Yes I do. I wrote it three times already.

Comment: No, you did not. Just read the beginning of section 3.1. As you wrote (three times),  the elements of $\tilde C^{0,\:\beta}$ are continuous by definition. So, for each $(\omega,t)$ the function $A_t(\omega):\Lambda\times\Lambda\to\mathbb R$ is continuous. However, in theorem 3.1.1 Kunita is talking about "continuous $\tilde C^{0,\:\beta}$-processes" and, clearly, that continuity notion has to be understood as a path property.

Comment: Meanwhile, I think he's meaning that $A$ considered as a stochastic process with parameter triple $(t,x,y)\in\overline I\times Λ\times Λ$ is continuous, i.e. $A(ω):\overline I\times\Lambda\times\Lambda\to\mathbb R$ is continuous for all $ω∈Ω$. At the time of asking the question, I thought he would mean that $t\mapsto A_t(ω)∈\tilde C^{0,\:β}$ is continuous for all $ω$. With the new interpretation, I don't see why $\tau$ is a stopping time. Maybe $t\mapsto\left\|A_t\right\|_{\tilde C^{0,\:β}}$ is continuous ... I've asked a [question for that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2865271/47771).